# Does a client need Mathematica kernel to run Mathematica code embedded in Java?

Tags: interoperability, deployment

I have built a predictive model using `Classify`. Its performance is great. Now I want to put it into production, and run it on the client side, where the client may not have *Mathematica*. Does the client has to have a *Mathematica* license (i.e., own a *Mathematica* kernel license) to run my code, even when the code is embedded in Java?

Comment: Did you try to run it as a client? That's the easy way to find out.

Comment: You could `CloudDeploy` an `APIFunction` which is a REST implementation, or `CloudDeploy` a `FormFunction` Although these have additional monetary costs (Cloud Credits) to consider

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/478njk/im_stephen_wolframask_me_anything/#d0b2495

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Thank You All!  to m_glodberg: I will try to run it as a client in another of my machines. I noticed that  one can create an C Mathematica executable.  If it is executable than it shouldn't need Mathematica Kernel at the Client side